# How do we load test HKClinicalRecord data into HealthKit?

Tags: healthkit, hl7-fhir

Yesterday Apple announced their [health records API](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/apple-opens-health-records-api-to-developers/).

The [documentation for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/health_and_fitness_samples/accessing_clinical_records) states that:

> ...clinical records are read-only, so you can’t request authorization to share clinical record types. You can’t create or save new HKClinicalRecord objects.

If I want to do some prototyping, and I don't work for one of the hospitals or clinics Apple currently supports, how can I load data into HealthKit to test reading and using this data in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beta 2 will have test accounts you can use from Simulator so you can test the integration with HealthKit. If you have specific FHIR patient data that you want to test with you can mock their delivery within your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Sandbox endpoints from the SMART ON FHIR project: http://docs.smarthealthit.org/data/dstu2-sandbox-data.html

This Sandbox also provides SMART on FHIR auth so you should be able to use it for testing purposes.

edit: you also could use:

- the HSCP Sandbox: https://sandbox.hspconsortium.org/#/start
- EPIC Sandbox: https://open.epic.com/AppExchange/Sandbox
- Allscript: https://developer.allscripts.com/Content/fhir/content/Smart%20on%20FHIR/
- Cerner: https://engineering.cerner.com/smart-on-fhir-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the great resources!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't! I have the same issue. This represents a serious gap in adoption for FHIR data using the Apple API approach. What is needed is a test hospital with some dummy or test accounts. This would be like the dummy accounts Used by Cerner and Epic for sandbox testing (Jason A., etc...). Ideally you would then login to the sandbox health group with this dummy account and get the data loaded that way. Since you cannot create the test data like you can for other Healthkit data objects this is real problem. The only way to prototype is use your own account at one of the hospitals that support this new feature but how many developers can do this, not many. Someone needs to solve this or this feature will never take off. Ideally we need at least one test record for each FHIR object type. (Condition, Procedure, etc...). I share your pain...

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in prototyping with FHIR resources, check out [HAPI FHIR Project](http://hapifhir.io/). The HAPI FHIR project has a server you can install (or a public server) where you can exchange FHIR resources. Retrieve and Submit.

I'm not sure this will help with the Apple HealthKit, but it might be a place to start. The FHIR standard is changing quickly and support around what is existing is limited. The Apple implementation is based on DSTU2, but the HAPI project already supports DSTU3.

Comment: HAPI actually supports always the newest FHIR Version, which is currently R4. And yes FHIR is not a normative Standard atm, but it isn't changing that fast, especially not the more mature resources.